# Object Oriented Programming correct use interface

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to design a few classes for a game, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

I have two classes: `Actor` and `Building`.
These have a few subclasses: `Policeman`, `Fireman` and `PoliceStation`, `FireStation`.

I want to be able to put all these items together in a list to iterate through later, so I've added a base class: `GameEntity`. 
So what I have is this:

```
public abstract class GameEntity: 
{
    public GameEntity()
    {

    }       
}

public class Actor: GameEntity
{
    public int _speed;
    public TileSprite _UI;

    public Actor()
    {

    }

    public bool CollidesWith(Vector2 pos)
    {
        //Do stuff here
    }

    public virtual void OnClick()
    {
        //Do stuff here
    }

    public void DoActing()
    {

    }
}

public class Policeman: Actor
{
    public Policeman()
    {
        _speed = 10;
    }

    public override void OnClick()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}

public class Building: GameEntity
{
    public TileSprite _UI;

    public Building()
    {

    }

    public bool CollidesWith(Vector2 pos)
    {
        //Do stuff here
    }

    public virtual void OnClick()
    {
        //Do stuff here
    }

    public void DoBuilding()
    {

    }
}

public class PoliceStation: Building
{
    public PoliceStation()
    {

    }

    public override void OnClick()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Now, I want to be able to do this:

```
List<GameEntity> Entities = new List<GameEntity>();

Actor a1 = new PoliceMan();
Building b1 = new PoliceStation

Entities.Add(a1);
Entities.Add(b1);

foreach(GameEntity ent in Entities)
{
    if (ent.CollidesWith(something))
    {
        ent.OnClick();

        //If Actor then do 
        ent.DoActing();

        //If Building then do
        ent.DoBuilding();
    }
}
```

Now, in order to do the last bit, would it be best if I implement an interface that contains the `OnClick` and `CollidesWith`, or can I do it with inheritance?
If so, how would I do this?

Cheers.

Comment: I would put your entity list in a World class. Later on, when you'll have more entities, you don't want to check all against all. You only want to check collision for moving object and only against object that are near.

Answer (score 2):

This is only to give you the idea, I guess that's what you need.

```
 public interface IGameEntity
    {
        bool CollidesWith();
        void OnClick();
        void DoActing();
    }
  public class Actor : IGameEntity { //Interface implemented }
  public class Building: IGameEntity { //Interface implemented }
  public class Policeman: IGameEntity { //Interface implemented }
  public class Fireman: IGameEntity { //Interface implemented }
  public class FireStation: IGameEntity { //Interface implemented }
```

In your client object just do something like this:

```
List<IGameEntity> entities = new List<IGameEntity>()
{
    new Actor(), 
    new Building(), 
    new Policeman(), 
    new Fireman(), 
    new Fireman()
};
foreach (IGameEntity entity in entities)
{
    entity.CollidesWith();
    entity.OnClick();
    entity.DoActing();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a virtual `doStuff()` to `GameEntity` and overriding it in the child classes instead of having unique method names like `DoActing` and `DoBuilding` then calling that from your loop should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Number of ways to go here.
If all GameEntities can be clicked on then you could add an OnClick event property to the base class.

If Not then I'd have an Interface IClick and then implement that on clickable entities.

Collision, depends.
Building don't move about so they can't collide with anything, but they can be collided with and so for instance you might want do a damage rountine, which then suggests a destroyed, routine a repair routine maybe.

There's no right answer, but
Three code smells would be a
A Base class with nothing in it.

A very deep inheritance hierarchy (more than two levels is cause for suspicion in my book)
So if you start seeing GameEntity -> BuildingEntity -> ActiveBuildingEntity -> RepairableBuildingEntity, you are in a mess that's about to get messier.

And above all a base class with do nothing methods in it that only exist because you need to add behaviour (override) in some descendants.

Don't be scared about having a few interfaces. IClick, ICollision, IDamage, IRepair etc. It's way better than implying a building can crash into a car.

Comment: Say I add different interfaces, specific for some classes. 
For example, I would give the Actor class the interface `IMove` containing the function `Move()`.
If I then have them all heaped together in the `List<IGameEntity>`, how can I call this function? Will I need to do a cast to `Actor` first?

Comment: Yes you would have to cast, in fact check and cast. But, why would you use List<IGameEntity> for moving. Another list List<IMove> ie when you create an entity that implements Imove, add it to both lists.

Comment: You have say mobile home then that's mainly static but occasionally moves about with a simple IsMoving property and then add it to both if it is. Nothing that deal with Move, should care about why or when, if its in the list it moves.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
    public interface IGameEntity
    {
        void OnClick();
        bool CollidesWith(Vector2 pos);
        void Do();
    }

    public abstract class Actor: IGameEntity
    {
        public int _speed;
        public TileSprite _UI;

        public virtual bool CollidesWith(Vector2 pos)
        {
            //Do stuff here
        }

        // can be marked virtual with implementation if you want a default
        // this way base classes will be forced to implement their own implementation
        public abstract void OnClick();

        // can be marked virtual with implementation if you want a default
        // this way base classes will be forced to implement their own implementation
        public abstract void Do();
    }

    public class Policeman: Actor
    {
        public Policeman()
        {
            _speed = 10;
        }

        public override void OnClick()
        {
            //Do stuff
        }

        public override void Do()
        {
            //Do Acting for Police
        }
    }

    public abstract class Building: IGameEntity
    {
        public TileSprite _UI;

        public bool CollidesWith(Vector2 pos)
        {
            //Do stuff here
        }

        public abstract void OnClick();

        public abstract void Do();
    }

    public class PoliceStation: Building
    {
        public PoliceStation()
        {

        }

        public override void OnClick()
        {
            //Do stuff
        }

        public override void Do()
        {
            // Do Building
        }
    }
```

If Game Entity is just an interface then there is no need to make it an abstract class.  If Actor and Building can never exist as a stand alone object then they should be abstract.  If DoActing, DoBuilding, and OnClick must be overridden by the base classes then you can mark them abstract in actor and Building.

I followed norlesh's suggestion to just have one method Do.  You could also make Actor and Building have their own abstract methods and IGameEntity would not have Do.  Then you would put an if statement and check the if each object is of type builder then they would run the build and if of type actor then run act.

I think the way of having one method is better, since you eliminate one step.  From a design perspective I'm not sure but it feels the same to me either way.

```
List<IGameEntity> Entities = new List<IGameEntity>();

Actor a1 = new PoliceMan();
Building b1 = new PoliceStation();

Entities.Add(a1);
Entities.Add(b1);

foreach(IGameEntity ent in Entities)
{
    if (ent.CollidesWith(something))
    {
        ent.OnClick();

        ent.Do();
    }
}
```

Comment: P.S.  I would no really name the method Do.  I would name it something like PostClickBehavior or PostClickProcessing or something like that.

Comment: I remain suspicious on putting CollidesWith in IGameEntity. About the only time a building moves into a vehicle's path, is on an insurance claim. :)

Comment: LOL. yeah I was thinking its more like Collides with a tank (the tank is moving not the house)

Comment: You could argue it either way, depends on whether you want to segregate collide and collision. It's the sort of "is a" / "has a" decision that can get you in a bit of a mess when using inheritance.